# Pandas: If a value in a field is None/null/NaN, append the name of the field to a new field

Tags: python, pandas, null

I am stumped on how to approach a particular problem. Basically, I wish to do the following:

Using pandas, I want to iterate through rows and, if a value in a field is None/NaN, append the name of the field to a new field as shown below.

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------+
| ID | Animal | Building | Letter | Fruit  | Number |           NullFields            |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | Dog    | House    | C      | null   | 4      | Fruit                           |
|  2 | null   | House    | null   | Apple  | null   | Animal, Letter, Number          |
|  3 | Cat    | null     | B      | Orange | null   | Building, Number                |
|  4 | null   | null     | null   | null   | 6      | Animal, Building, Letter, Fruit |
|  5 | Snake  | null     | A      | null   | 7      | Building, Fruit                 |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Above I've typed out 'null' for readability. I know None/NaN are not the same, but the data I'm dealing with appears to have both. If I have to run `fillna` that's fine.

I don't think `np.where` is going to work here unless I'm missing something. I don't know if maybe I need to use `iterrows` instead or what.

Any tips/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: are those `None/null/NaN` the `None` value or the respective string values?

Comment: None. So wherever the value is null basically. So where you see "null" above it means nothing, not the value of a string.

Comment: One thing that occurred to me (but something that would be messy) is to do something like this:

`df['Test1'] = np.where(((df['Animal'].isnull())  'Name of Field', None)`
\n
`df['Test2'] = np.where(((df['Building'].isnull())  'Name of Field', None)`

for every single column and then add the results...This doesn't seem to be a very efficient approach and in actuality I have 20 fields to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

```
# if ID is index, then just `df` instead of `df.iloc[...]
s = df.iloc[:,1:].isna()
df['NullFields'] = (s @ (s.columns + (', '))).str.strip(', ')
```

Output:

```
   ID Animal Building Letter   Fruit  Number                       NullFields
0   1    Dog    House      C     NaN     4.0                            Fruit
1   2    NaN    House    NaN   Apple     NaN           Animal, Letter, Number
2   3    Cat      NaN      B  Orange     NaN                 Building, Number
3   4    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN     6.0  Animal, Building, Letter, Fruit
4   5  Snake      NaN      A     NaN     7.0                  Building, Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

First its required to make true `NaN` fields to measure if they are null then we can use `isnull` followed by `.dot`

```
df['NullableFields'] = df.replace("null", np.nan).isnull().dot(df.columns)

print(df)

    ID   Animal   Building   Letter   Fruit    Number   \
0     1      Dog      House        C     null        4   
1     2     null      House     null    Apple     null   
2     3      Cat       null        B   Orange     null   
3     4     null       null     null     null        6   
4     5    Snake       null        A     null        7   

             NullFields                                 NullableFields  
0                            Fruit                             Fruit    
1           Animal, Letter, Number             Animal  Letter  Number   
2                 Building, Number                   Building  Number   
3  Animal, Building, Letter, Fruit   Animal  Building  Letter  Fruit    
4                  Building, Fruit                   Building  Fruit
```

Comment: Thanks! Always good to know there's more than one way to approach a problem!